# Laravel API URL Error

Tags: laravel-4

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1', 'before' => 'auth.basic'), function()
    {
        Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
        Route::resource('messages', 'MessagesController');
    });
```

The code above is in my `route.php`.  My problem is how to access it from a mobile app.

I tried:

```
http://192.***.**.**/mywebsite/public/index.php/api/v1/users/1
```

**AND**

```
http://192.***.**.**/mywebsite/api/v1/users/1
```

I get errors using both. Please, how do I solve this?

Comment: First what error? Second Your controllers are in root Controller directory or some where else in inner directory.

Comment: they are in the controllers directory. I get 404 error

Comment: Have you tried `Route::resource('users', 'api/v1/UsersController');`

Comment: nope, does that mean I should create a the following folders `api/v1`?

Comment: When you are having prefixes,  its a good practice to have folders like this. But in that case you also need to handle name spaces in your controller. Any Laravel Class will not be directly accessible. You need to use namespace at top of your controller

Comment: I am relatively new on this, can I have an example please?

Answer (score 0):

can you see the Route::get('/') on your mobile? if no then your server isnt setup correct, you could even try to go to

```
http://192.***.**.**/api/v1/users/1
```